# Azure Search on Complex Field

Tags: python, azure, azure-cognitive-search, azure-search-.net-sdk

I have an index created with these fields:

```
fields = [
        SimpleField(name="key", type=SearchFieldDataType.String, key=True),

        SearchableField(name="type", type=SearchFieldDataType.String, sortable=True),
        # SearchableField(name="unitRef", type=SearchFieldDataType.String, analyzer_name="en.lucene"),
        
        ComplexField(name="period", fields=[
            SimpleField(name="startDate", type=SearchFieldDataType.DateTimeOffset, facetable=True, filterable=True, sortable=True),
            SimpleField(name="endDate", type=SearchFieldDataType.DateTimeOffset, facetable=True, filterable=True, sortable=True)
      
        ]),
        # ComplexField(name="segment", fields=[
        #     SearchableField(name="dimension", type=SearchFieldDataType.String),
        #     SearchableField(name="value", type=SearchFieldDataType.String)
      
        # ]),

        SimpleField(name="value", type=SearchFieldDataType.Double, facetable=True, filterable=True, sortable=True)

        #  ComplexField(name="segment", fields=[
        #     SearchableField(name="dimension", type=SearchFieldDataType.String),
        #     SearchableField(name="value", type=SearchFieldDataType.String, facetable=True, filterable=True, sortable=True)
      
        # ]),


    ]
```

I want to filter my peroid within a certain date, I am using this code but it's not working:

```
results = search_client.search(search_text="RevenueFromContractWithCustomerExcludingAssessedTax", select='type,period,value',filter="period ge 2020-01-01 and period le 2021-12-31", include_total_count=True)

print ('Total Documents Matching Query:', results.get_count())
for result in results:
    print("type: {}, period: {}, value: {}".format(result["type"],result["period"],result["value"]))
    dat= ("type: {}, period: {}, value: {}".format(result["type"],result["period"],result["value"]))
    # print(result)
```

Would appreciate the feedback, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this:

```
results = search_client.search(
    search_text="RevenueFromContractWithCustomerExcludingAssessedTax",
    select='type,period,value',
    filter="period/any(p: p/startDate ge 2020-01-01 and p/endDate le 2021-12-31)",
    include_total_count=True
)


print ('Total Documents Matching Query:', results.get_count())
for result in results:
    print("type: {}, period: {}, value: {}".format(result["type"],result["period"],result["value"]))
    dat= ("type: {}, period: {}, value: {}".format(result["type"],result["period"],result["value"]))
    # print(result)
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I got this error:

HttpResponseError: () Invalid expression: Any/All may only be used following a collection.
Parameter name: $filter
Code: 
Message: Invalid expression: Any/All may only be used following a collection.
Parameter name: $filter
Output is truncated. View as a scrollable element or open in a text editor. Adjust cell output settings...

Comment: It's a complex field and not a collection so "any" isn't required. Try the following: "period/startDate ge 2020-01-01 and period/endDate le 2021-12-31"

Comment: I get this error now:
HttpResponseError: () Invalid expression: Literal '2021-12-31' of unsupported data type 'Date' was found. Please use a literal that matches the type of the field in the expression.
Parameter name: $filter
Code: 
Message: Invalid expression: Literal '2021-12-31' of unsupported data type 'Date' was found. Please use a literal that matches the type of the field in the expression.
Parameter name: $filter

Comment: Ok then try using the full ISO8601 DateTimeOffset syntax:  "period/startDate ge 2020-01-01T00:00:00Z and period/endDate le 2021-12-31T00:00:00Z"